# how to run many instances of an object simultaneously in pyqt pyside

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qthread

in below code a sample program which you can open new tab whenever you click " New " button and each tab contains QWebView browser (which used in PyQt/PySide) and " Start " button, when "Start" button clicked the browser load 3 sites one by one
the problem is:
when opened more than one tab and run all tabs or more than one tab, all other tabs pause loading until the last one finished loading and then the next resumes
I want to run them simultaneously how ?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *


class Main_Gui(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bt_new = QPushButton('New')
        self.tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.tabwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt_new)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.bt_new.clicked.connect(self.add_new)

    def add_new(self):
        br = browser()
        self.tabwidget.addTab(br, 'browser')


class browser(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.br = QWebView()
        self.bt_Start = QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.br)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt_Start)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.bt_Start.clicked.connect(self.start_load)

    def start_load(self):
        self.th = QThread()
        self.th.started.connect(self.load)
        self.th.start()

    def load(self):
        sites = ['https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/'
            , 'http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python', 'http://www.google.com']
        for i in sites:
            self.br.load(QUrl(i))
            self.sleep(20)

    def sleep(self, seconds):
        end = QTime.addSecs(QTime.currentTime(), seconds)
        while end > QTime.currentTime():
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Main_Gui()
win.resize(800, 600)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander he gave me the clue and hereunder full code for the example I submitted in my question, the problem was I want to tell the QThread to wait until page loads and I found a solution to make a local variable called loaded in the QThread and connected the browser loadFinished signal to function makes the loaded variable true when loading finished , in the Qthread i made wait code until loaded var becomes true

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from Browser_AutoPilot import BrowserAutoPilot


class Main_Gui(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bt_new = QPushButton('New')
        self.tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.tabwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt_new)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.bt_new.clicked.connect(self.add_new)

    def add_new(self):
        br = browser()
        self.tabwidget.addTab(br, 'browser')


class browser(QWidget):
    load_finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.br = BrowserAutoPilot()
        self.bt_Start = QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.br)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt_Start)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.th = TimerThread()
        self.bt_Start.clicked.connect(self.start_load)

    def start_load(self):
        self.stop_thread(self.th)

        self.th.nextURL.connect(self.load_url_slot)
        self.br.loadFinished.connect(self.wait_loading)
        self.th.start()

    def load_url_slot(self, url):
        self.br.load(QUrl(url))

    def wait_loading(self):
        self.th.loaded = True

    def stop_thread(self, thread):
        thread.terminate()
        if thread.isRunning():
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    def sleep(self, seconds):
        end = QTime.addSecs(QTime.currentTime(), seconds)
        while end > QTime.currentTime():
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()


class TimerThread(QThread):
    nextURL = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, loaded=False):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.loaded = loaded

    def run(self):
        sites = ['https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/',
                 'http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python', 'http://www.google.com']

        for url in sites:
            print(self.thread(), url)
            self.nextURL.emit(url)
            self.loaded = False
            while not self.loaded:
                self.sleep(1)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Main_Gui()
win.resize(800, 600)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign no work to your `QThread`s (do not reimplement `run` method). `browser.load` slot, which you've connected with `th.started` signal, executes in main thread (because your browsers are created in it). That causes your issue.

Besides, you can make changes to the GUI (e.g. call `self.br.load` method) only from main thread (for the sake of thread safety).

```
class TimerThread(QThread):
    nextURL = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        sites = ['https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/',
                 'http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python', 'http://www.google.com']
        for url in sites:
            print(self.thread(), url)
            self.nextURL.emit(url)
            self.sleep(10)


class browser(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        [...]
        self.th = QThread()

    def start_load(self):
        self.stop_thread(self.th)
        self.th = TimerThread()
        self.th.nextURL.connect(self.load_url_slot)
        self.th.start()

    def load_url_slot(self, url):
        self.br.load(QUrl(url))

    def stop_thread(self, thread):
        thread.terminate()
        if thread.isRunning():
            QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: That's good, but I still have an issue which I want to tell Qthread to wait for page loading not certain time, actually I want to know how to send a notification to TimerThread that webview has finished loading and you can go for the next loop iteration and emit the second signal